# Unable to import card in Hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to deploy a business network to Hyperledger Fabric runtime by following Hyperledger Composer tutorial on "Deploying a Hyperledger Composer blockchain business network to Hyperledger Fabric (multiple organizations)". But whenever I try to import a network card to the network, it gives an error specifying that "Errors found in the connection profile in the card". How can I solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: which version of composer are you using ? composer 0.19.13 doesn't mandate eventUrl existing in the connection profile any more

Comment: v0.19.12. Should I update it to 0.19.13?

Comment: I would recommend going to 0.19.13

Comment: Thanks. It works. (Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composer 0.19.13 has removed the mandatory requirement for eventUrl being present in the connection profile as it isn't required. Previous versions prior to this release will result in the error seen here if your connection profile doesn't contain the eventUrl entries. Composer documentation was updated when 0.19.13 was released to remove these redundant entries.